# Stratify and model evaluation

Tags: scikit-learn, evaluation

I want evaluate three models i.e. `LogisticRegression` , `SVM`  and `Random Forest` using an imbalanced dataset. I decided to use a stritified method.
The first option is to use `train_test_split` and set the `stratyfy=y`
Howerever I used the `StratifyKfold`  method with 10 splits.
In this case how do i evaluate my three models using the same splits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same dataset, you can fix the `random_state` parameter of the `StratifyKfold`. If you do that, you would be evaluating the three models with same 10 splits.